# Python socket.recv Closing Socket Prematurely

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, tcp, telnet, recv

I have a web proxy that starts a TCP listener socket that accepts connections from clients. The listener accepts connections via:

```
clientConnection, clientAddress = listenerSocket.accept()
```

and then a new thread handles the client connection from there.

To mock a client connection, I am using `telnet` to connect to the proxy and issue commands. The proxy needs to receive data from `telnet` and I need to make sure that I receive all of it. To achieve this, I am doing the following:

```
while True:
    requestBytes = clientConnection.recv(1024)

    if not requestBytes:
        break

    requestBuffer += requestBytes
```

The proxy then decodes the bytes and does some things with them that takes a little bit of time, and then has to **send a response back to the same client.** However, when using the above code the connection with `clientConnection` gets closed long before I can process the bytes and respond.

Here's what I don't understand, when I use the following instead:

```
while True:
    requestBytes = clientConnection.recv(1024)
    requestBuffer += requestBytes
    break
```

It works just fine and the `clientConnection` remains intact. This obviously has a problem if I receive more than 1024 bytes, but the `clientConnection` does **not** get closed.

More specifically, the error occurs after I have a response to send to the client and call:

```
clientConnection.sendall(response)
clientConnection.shutdown(1)
clientConnection.close()
```

The line `clientConnection.shutdown(1)` throws the error:

```
[Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

which is confusing because somehow it was able to still call `sendall` on the previous line. *Note that I did not actually receive anything on the client side.*

I am sure that the connection is not getting closed elsewhere in the code. What exactly is happening here and what is the best way to do something like `recvall` *and* keep the `clientConnection` open?

Comment: No idea, but shutdown before close is redundant. Just get rid of it. You will probably now get the error on the close.

Comment: Where is the code that checks to see if you've received all of the message? Most likely, the bug is in that code, and you haven't shown it. (If you have no such code, then that's your problem. You have to actually implement a message protocol if you want to receive messages.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This works! However, I did not think it would be necessary as reading "terminating characters" and reading until the client stops sending *appears* synonymous, at least from my end. There must be something with `socket.recv` that results in a difference and ultimately closing the connection, but the API does not signify what exactly it is. Either way, thank you for the help!

Comment: In any case you should not accumulate the entire response before sending any of it. This just wastes time and space. You don't want the added latency. Just send it on as you get it.

Comment: @EJP The problem is that I need to look at the message as a whole before I can do anything with it, messages come in various formats/lengths as well and do not have consistent terminating characters so at this point I am just going to utilize a timeout.

Comment: @ThoseKind How do you know when the client stops sending?